# Why Yuv data readed from ffmpeg is different from original input yuv?

Tags: ffmpeg, hdr

I use ffmpeg to make HDR test video, my approach is write a image, converting the image to yuv420p and then use ffmpeg to make the HDR test video.

But I found the yuv data readed from mp4 is different from the original input..
I was stucked in here for a while, does anyone know how to read the correct yuv data from mp4 ?

```
#ffmpeg encode command
ffmpeg_encode_mp4 = \
"ffmpeg -y -s 100*100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 4 -r 1 -stream_loop -1 -f rawvideo -i write_yuv.yuv -vf \
scale=out_h_chr_pos=0:out_v_chr_pos=0,format=yuv420p10le \
-c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -preset medium -x265-params \
crf=12:colorprim=bt2020:transfer=smpte2084:colormatrix=bt2020nc:master-display=\"G(13250,34500)B(7500,3000)R(34000,16000)WP(15635,16450)L(10000000,1)\":max-cll=\"1000,400\" \
-an test.mp4"

#ffmpeg read yuv from mp4 command
ffmpeg_extract_yuv = "ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p read_yuv.yuv"


#make 100*100 yuv raw
w, h = 100, 100
test_gray = 255
test = np.full((100, 100, 3), test_gray, dtype=np.uint8)
yuv_cv = cv.cvtColor(test, cv.COLOR_RGB2YUV_I420)
yuv_cv.tofile("write_yuv.yuv")

#encode yuv raw to mp4 with HDR metadata
print(ffmpeg_encode_mp4)
result = subprocess.check_output(ffmpeg_encode_mp4, shell = True)
print(result)
sleep(0.5)

#extract yuv from mp4
kill_existing_file("read_yuv.yuv")
print(ffmpeg_extract_yuv)
result = subprocess.check_output(ffmpeg_extract_yuv, shell = True)
print(result)
sleep(0.5)

write_yuv = np.fromfile("write_yuv.yuv",dtype='uint8')
read_yuv = np.fromfile("read_yuv.yuv",dtype='uint8')

print("input gray:", test_gray)
print("write_yuv", write_yuv[:10])
print("read_yuv", read_yuv[:10])

reader = imageio.get_reader("test.mp4")
img = reader.get_data(0)
print("imgeio read:", img[50, 50])

'''
ouput result:
input gray: 255
write_yuv [235 235 235 235 235 235 235 235 235 235]
read_yuv [234 235 234 235 234 235 234 235 234 235]
imgeio read: [253 253 253]
'''
```

I have no idea how to validate the video I made is corret
Any feedback will be very appreciated!

Comment: Encoding video is not a lossless process. Small bits of information get lost or distorted. That is how video compression works.

Comment: So, does it mean the difference I saw is expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use ffplay -vf extractplanes=y (also can use u, v, r, g, b, a).

For 10 bit please use ffmpeg -vf extractplanes=y to png and the 16 bit colorpicker in GIMP, because there is some problem in ffplay.